# Как в Monosnap на Mac`е включить пассивный режим FTP?

Tags: ftp

В Monosnap на Mac`е нету пассивного режима FTP. Вот скрин настроек

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на винде есть чекбокс, который позволяет включить пассивный режим FTP. Вот скрин настроек

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно включить пассивный режим FTP на Mac OS?

Comment: что то мне кажется, что там просто неправильно перевели на русский язык:)

Comment: Нет, с переводом у них все норм, просто можно врубить анонимный режим FTP, а вот что с пассивным, непонятно)